# How can I find the most frequent county using data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:
Customer (cnp, customer_no, city, county)
Accounts (account_number, customer_no, balance)
Cards (card_id, account_number, card_number, exp_date)

Select the COUNTY where are the most CARDS that expired in the current month.

Tried this method:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 Customer.county, COUNT(Customer.county) AS county_count
FROM Customer
JOIN Accounts ON Customer.customer_no = Accounts.customer_no
JOIN Cards ON Accounts.account_number = Cards.account_number
WHERE Cards.exp_date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY Customer.county
ORDER BY county_count DESC;
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't quite make sense"* What doesn't make sense about the dataset up got?

Comment: Also, note that `WHERE Cards.exp_date = CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )` would return rows for the current date (provided that `exp_date` is a `date` or all the values are at the time `00:00:00`), *not* the current month.

Comment: I need only a row with the most frequent county where the exp_date is from the current month. The date is of format "yyyy/mm/dd".

Comment: Yes, you said what you want in the question, I'm asking what about the attempt you made don't you understand, as you said that it "didn't make sense". What about the query/result set didn't you understand?

Comment: Update your post with sample data and expected output: it will most likely make everybody understand what you're looking for.

Comment: *"The date is of format "yyyy/mm/dd""* So are you storing your dates as a `(n)varchar`? That's a fatal design flaw. For a date and time value you a date and time data type, which don't have a "format", they are stored as binary values. `(n)(var)char` (string based) data types are completely unsuitable for date and time values.

Comment: @Larnu used an online database and it doesn't make sense to me because I can't test exactly the query. I wanted to know if its good written. Worked previously with Oracle and SQL Server is a bit different.

Comment: Also, GETDATE() will only return the current day, but I need for an entire month.

Comment: If you can't test the query, how will you be able to validate any answer we give you? If you can't run the query, then how do you know what data is in the table? You first need to be using an environment you can actually use.

Comment: Yes, I already [covered that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061191/how-can-i-find-the-most-frequent-county-using-data-from-another-table?noredirect=1#comment132460433_75061191),  @MeLlmaoEphteban . You need to use a date range instead.

Comment: @Larnu I will set up the env now and test the query with a date range. Thank you

Comment: @Larnu I have tried this query but EXTRACT or NOW doesn't work in SSMS. Is there any way I can work around this? Edited the question

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't post your attempts in the comments.

Comment: Also added the FK for a better understanding. Tried to create a separate table from Cards then JOIN the other two in order to use COUNT..

Comment: @Larnu sorry for another ping, managed to workaround and change the code using the date interval that you mentioned. The query return one row but is not the correct county. I have 5 rows, 3 of them have the county "BC" and 2 of them have "CJ". The result indicates "CJ". Also edited the post. Thank you

Comment: With no consumable sample data, I cannot comment, @MeLlmaoEphteban .